# Fragment.onViewCreated java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have sometimes this error in Crashlytics. It not always only 10-15 times per 1000 sessions but I haven't been able to get rid of it.

If I check the events it doesn't show a lot of it. Some times is only session_start, some times notification_dismissed, and some times notification_receive.

The code that i use is:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       if (prefs.notificationViewControler == "") {
            val needToShow = prefs.needToShow
            if (needToShow) {
                prefs.fechaUltimaPulbicidad=currentDate
                isAdsOpen = true
                //Revisar Si existe la actiidad
                if (isAdded) {
                    //FindView
                    val bundle = bundleOf("isFirstInstall" to 0)
                    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),R.id.fragment_container)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.action_principalFragment_to_fragmentAds,bundle)
                }

            }
        } else {
            prefs.notificationViewControler = ""
        }

    }
```

I used **prefs.prefs.notificationViewControler** to try to distinguish if the app comes from a notification.